# Angular 8, Angular Flex Layout: this._delegate.setClass is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout, angular8

Updating to Angular 8, all my code that uses angular flex and has ngClass is broken:

```
<div class="pages-container"
       [ngClass.lt-md]="{'mobile-no-padding': true}">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

returns an error upon rendering:
`ERROR TypeError: this._delegate.setClass is not a function`

Was only able to resolve this by removing the dynamic responsive suffix (`[ngClass]="{'mobile-no-padding': true}`) but that's a big stepback...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue with `ngClass` after the update to angular version 8. After updating `@angular/flex-layout` to version `^8.0.0-beta.26` the issue was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you reinstall your flex layout this'll get fixed

> npm i @angular/flex-layout --save

Comment: thanks for the answer, but sadly this did not help.

Comment: @ForestG, Can you change the  [ngClass.lt-md] to  [class.lt-md] and see what happens?

Comment: it runs without an error, but my classes will never get applied.

Comment: I'm sorry but nothing else comes to my mind, maybe if you add a StackBlitz we could help you more

Comment: Stackblitz is still using Angular 7.2 :\

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't help